# ACF Relationship - Limit to specific pages

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

In Advanced Custom Fields, I would like limit the Relationship field (http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/) to specific pages.

For various resons, involing Custom Post Types is not a solution for me right now.

This is my sitemap:

```
website.com
website.com/contact/
website.com/help/
website.com/map/
website.com/hunting-products/
website.com/hunting-products/scopes/
website.com/hunting-products/rifles/
website.com/fishing-products/
website.com/fishing-products/fishing-rods/
website.com/fishing-products/bait/
```

In the Relationship field, and I would like to filter this so you only can select these products.

```
website.com/hunting-products/scopes/
website.com/hunting-products/rifles/
website.com/fishing-products/fishing-rods/
website.com/fishing-products/bait/
```

Comment: If you read through the ACF documentation, [the relationship field has a filter you can hook to modify the query it uses to populate the field choices](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-fields-relationship-query/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution that works:

```
add_filter('acf/fields/relationship/query/name=products', 'exclude_id', 10, 3);

function exclude_id ( $args, $field, $post ) {

    $args['post__not_in'] = array( $post, 9, 10, 11 );

    return $args;
}
```

Added in functions. This will exclude the pages with id 9, 10 and 11.

Answer (score 0):

In `register_taxonomy` you can pass `page` as the associated post type and it will become an option on the edit screen

`register_taxonomy( 'custom_tax', 'page', $args );`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Comment: I can already choose pages, so that is not them problem. I would rather want to block out pages that is not using the template I want.

Answer (score 0):

I had the quite similar issue. I needed to **restrict** Relationship Fields Choices to **posts owned by Current User** but grant a full access to “editor” & “administrator”.

Here is the code inserted in the `functions.php` file

```
<?php
function modify_field( $args, $field,$post) {
    if( !check_user_role(array('editor','administrator')) ){
        $args['author'] = get_current_user_id();
    }
    return $args;
}

    add_filter( 'acf/fields/post_object/query/key=field_XXX..XXX', 'modify_field', 10, 3 );

/* @src & @credits https://wp-mix.com/wordpress-check-user-roles/ */
function check_user_role($roles, $user_id = null) {
    if ($user_id) $user = get_userdata($user_id);
    else $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if (empty($user)) return false;

    foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
        if (in_array($role, $roles)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
?>
```